# Parallelize four and more nested loops with CUDA

Tags: c++, loops, parallel-processing, cuda

I am working on a compiler generating parallel C++ code. I am new to CUDA programming but I am trying to parallelize the C++ code with CUDA.

Currently if I have the following sequential C++ code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < c; k++) {
            A[i*y*z + j*z + k*z +l] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

and this results in the following CUDA code:

```
__global__ void kernelExample() {
    int _cu_x = ((blockIdx.x*blockDim.x)+threadIdx.x);
    int _cu_y = ((blockIdx.y*blockDim.y)+threadIdx.y);
    int _cu_z = ((blockIdx.z*blockDim.z)+threadIdx.z);

    A[_cu_x*y*z + _cu_y*z + _cu_z] = 1;
}
```

so each loop nest is mapped to one dimension, but what would be the correct way to parallelize four and more nested loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < c; k++) {
            for(int l = 0; l < d; l++) {
                A[i*x*y*z + j*y*z + k*z +l] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any similar way? Noteworthy: all loop dimensions are parallel and there are no dependencies between iterations.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: the goal is to map all iterations to CUDA threads, since all iterations are independent and could be executed concurrently.

Comment: For N nested loops, you use N dimensions. You don't have to stick to the 3 dimensions provided by CUDA, just calculate your own indices.

Comment: Could you please provide a solution for my example with four nested loops?

Comment: The solution is trivial but this text entry field is too small for it.

Comment: Maybe you write an answer? Or is this too much effort? Would appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

You could keep the outer loop unchanged. Also it is better to use `.x` as inner most loop so you can [access the global memory efficiently](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-c-kernels/).

```
__global__ void kernelExample() {
    int _cu_x = ((blockIdx.x*blockDim.x)+threadIdx.x);
    int _cu_y = ((blockIdx.y*blockDim.y)+threadIdx.y);
    int _cu_z = ((blockIdx.z*blockDim.z)+threadIdx.z);
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        A[i*x*y*z + _cu_z*y*z + _cu_y*z + _cu_x] = 1;
    }
}
```

However if your `a,b,c,d` are all very small, you may not be able to get enough parallelism. In that case you could convert a linear index to n-D indices.

```
__global__ void kernelExample() {
    int tid = ((blockIdx.x*blockDim.x)+threadIdx.x);
    int i = tid / (b*c*d);
    int j = tid / (c*d) % b;
    int k = tid / d % c;
    int l = tid % d;

    A[i*x*y*z + j*y*z + k*z + l] = 1;
}
```

But be careful that calculating `i,j,k,l` may introduce a lot of overhead as integer division and mod are slow on GPU. As an alternative you could map `i,j` to `.z` and `.y`, and calculate only `k,l` and more dimensions from `.x` in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i don't want to have any loops in my kernel since all iterations are independent and could be executed concurrently.

Comment: @siebenschlaefer With a large enough blockDim and gridDim, you probably have got enough parallelism already. It's ok to keep a loop.

Comment: that is true, but this is not the case in all source programs I am testing with.

Comment: In fact, keeping the loop in some scenarios may drive up the work per thread, which can improve performance vs. giving only a small amount of work to each thread.  You may actually expose more *usable* parallelism by increasing the work per thread vs. going to more threads.

Comment: If all your loop iterations are independent, then you can flatten or "collapse" loops.  This concept is not unique to cuda; it can be done in ordinary C/C++ code.  If you want to go to one loop iteration per thread, then collapse your loops in host code and perform the conversion to a grid for your kernel.

Comment: @RobertCovella This is what I want to check for various source programs and verify in which cases "going to more threads" makes sense.