# how to parallelize dct (for loops) in cuda

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, dct

How to parallelize four nested for loops in cuda
in case of dct i have four nested for loops i want my dct function in cuda code

```
for(y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y+=BLOCK_H) {
for(x = 0; x < WIDTH; x+= BLOCK_W) {
for(i = 0; i < BLOCK_H; i++) {
for(j = 0; j < BLOCK_W; j++) {
block_in[i][j] = cur_frame[(x+j)+(WIDTH*(y+i))];
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Think data, not loops. And read tutorials.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708101/parallelize-four-and-more-nested-loops-with-cuda) a question which asks about how to parallelize nested loops .  [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529387/kernel-for-processing-a-4d-tensor-in-cuda) another one.

Answer (score 3):

There is a white paper from Nvidia, Obukov and Kharlamov: [Discrete Cosine Transform for 8x8 Blocks with CUDA](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/dct8x8.pdf) that goes with dct8x8 in the [CUDA samples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/#dct8x8). You should have a look at both.

Comment: i read that but i didn't understand how they are doing this line in C 
SubroutineDCTvector((float *)fSrc + (i+k) * Stride + j, 1, fDst + (i+k) * Stride + j, 1);

Comment: And this in Cuda
int OffsThreadInRow = threadIdx.y * BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.x;
    int OffsThreadInCol = threadIdx.z * BLOCK_SIZE;
    src += FMUL(blockIdx.y * KER2_BLOCK_HEIGHT + OffsThreadInCol, ImgStride) + blockIdx.x * KER2_BLOCK_WIDTH + OffsThreadInRow;
    dst += FMUL(blockIdx.y * KER2_BLOCK_HEIGHT + OffsThreadInCol, ImgStride) + blockIdx.x * KER2_BLOCK_WIDTH + OffsThreadInRow;
    float *bl_ptr = block + OffsThreadInCol * KER2_SMEMBLOCK_STRIDE + OffsThreadInRow;